# Javascript IFrame Not Navigating on HREF Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<frameset rows="250px,*" onload="start_here();">
    <frame src="leftframe.htm" name="topo" id="topo" application="yes" />
    <frame src="leftframe.htm" name="link" id="link" />
</frameset>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">
function start_here()
{
        var usernameFromCookie = GetCookie(site);
        var urlToSite = createCustomURL(usernameFromCookie);
        alert(urlToSite);
}
function createCustomURL(userName)
{
        var customURL = "http://server1/get/cgi-app.exe?HOSTID=AD&ALIAS=" + userName;
        return customURL;
}
function setUserLink(urlFromCookie)
{
        $('a#link').attr('href', urlFromCookie);
}
```

I am trying to get the second frame (name is link) to redirect to the site

Comment: `<frameset>`?  What is this, 1995?  :-P

Comment: so start_here is never called?

Comment: Where is this javascript code located relative to all that html? did you check the javascript console for errors?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?  Where do you declare `GetCookie`?  Where do you call `setUserLink`?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt the frameset's onload is where the OP is trying to execute that

Comment: $('a#link') will look for <a> tag, not for <frame>

Comment: @StefanH lol i know, i meant like in actual execution is it called, not it is supposed to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to set the frame src.

```
$('#link').attr('src', urlFromCookie);
```

Comment: I assume you mean `frame#link`?

Comment: There's no need for jquery here as well: `document.getElementById('link').src = urlFromCookie`

Comment: Where is your JavaScript located? On the frameset page or on one of the other pages? If you are trying to change the frame src from within another frame you might need to use window.parent.